# PayPal Smart Payment Buttons - Alternative Payment Methods - 400 Bad Request

Tags: paypal

I'm using the PayPal Smart Payment Buttons on my website to capture payments.

The Order is created server-side via the PayPal-checkout-sdk for PHP.

```
 $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
 $request->prefer('return=representation');
 $request->body = self::buildRequestBody($paymentAC);
 // 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
 $client = PayPalClient::client();
 $response = $client->execute($request);
```

The request body looks like this:

```
return array(
        'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
        'commit' => true,
        'application_context' =>
            array(
                'brand_name' => 'EXAMPLE INC',
                'locale' => 'de-DE'
                'shipping_preference' => 'NO_SHIPPING'
            ),

        'purchase_units' =>
            array(
                0 =>
                    array(
                        'reference_id' => $rId,
                        'description' => 'Ihr kauf bei EXAMPLE INC',
                        'invoice_id' => $paymentAC,
                        'amount' =>
                            array(
                                'currency_code' => $currency, #EUR
                                'value' => $price,
                                'breakdown' =>
                                    array(
                                        'item_total' =>
                                            array(
                                                'currency_code' => $currency,
                                                'value' => $itemTotal,
                                            ),
                                        'tax_total' =>
                                            array(
                                                'currency_code' => $currency,
                                                'value' => 0,
                                            ),
                                    ),
                            ),
                        'items' => $items,
                    ),
            ),
    );
```

The request works fine and an order is created. The script returns a JSON Object with the "id" key set to the ID of the created order.

```
{"id": "PAYMENTID"}
```

The script is called by the payment button like this:

```
paypal.Buttons({
                                    createOrder: function() {
                                        return fetch('./CreateOrder.php', {
                                            method: 'post',
                                            headers: {
                                                'content-type': 'application/json'
                                            },
                                            body: '{"payment_ac": "<?php echo $_GET['code'] ?>"}'
                                        }).then(function(res) {
                                            console.log(res);
                                            return res.json();
                                        }).then(function(data) {
                                            return data.id; // Use the key sent by your server's response, ex. 'id' or 'token'
                                        });
                                    },
                                    onError: (err) => {
                                        console.error('error from the onError callback', err);
                                    },
                                    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                                        // This function captures the funds from the transaction.

                                        $("#loadMe").modal({
                                            backdrop: "static", //remove ability to close modal with click
                                            keyboard: false, //remove option to close with keyboard
                                            show: true //Display loader!
                                        });

                                        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                                            // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                                            console.log(details);
                                            //window.location.href = "verify.php?id=" + data.orderID + "&ac=<?php echo $internalID ?>";
                                            $.get({
                                                url: "/payment/verify.php?id=" + data.orderID + "&ac=<?php echo $internalID ?>",
                                                success: function (respdata) {
                                                    if (respdata['payment'] === "completed") {
                                                        window.location.href = '/success/<?php echo $internalID?>&cid=' + respdata['cid'];
                                                    } else {
                                                        alert(respdata);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            })
                                        });
                                    },
                                    onCancel: function (data) {
                                        console.log(data);
                                        alert(data);
                                        // Show a cancel page, or return to cart
                                        window.location.href = "/payment/cancelled.php?ac=<?php echo $internalID ?>&oid=" + data.orderID;
                                    },
                                    style: {
                                        color:   'black',
                                        label:   'pay',
                                        layout: 'vertical'
                                    }
                                }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

The payment buttons can open the checkout window successfully.

When I'm using sandbox credentials everything works fine. (PayPal, Simulated Alternative Payments & Credit Card payments)

When I'm switching to live credentials only PayPal payments seem to work. Every alternative payment method redirects to https://www.paypal.com/latinumcheckout/error/generic-error after you enter your details on https://www.paypal.com/latinumcheckout/change-userinfo

When in the developer console there is an error output:

```
the server responded with a status of 400 () app.bundle.js:41:140543
```

Credit card payments seem to fail as well.

I'm clueless, I spent a long time reading the documentation but have found no solution.

Comment: Does the live clientid/secret being used by the server match the live clientid being used by the button code? What is that id? You should include the entire button code and SDK script line in your question

Comment: Yes the client id in the script tag of the JS script belongs to the same app the server uses. The client id is: AehyR6BZgtq-ICY4vEQzJ4YuNPmZAkmTzkJnFGXywx8tU-ZXpsRQ4memDyA_dO76ck0yiXnlFm7ohopO

Comment: Try with another live PayPal account that is of type Business.

Comment: On the developer Dhasboard -> My Account it already says „Current account type: Business“

Comment: Doesn't matter, paypal.com will say it is Premier

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try as soon as I can.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is now working fine!